Vssop-10 IC XM01 code
Trying to identify a vssop-10 package smd IC with code XM01, 1810 written under.
Anyone has any idea what it could be?


Might be a MSOP10 from Cirrus Logic https://jlcpcb.com/partdetail/CirrusLogic-CS2100CPCZZR/C2663267

Don't think it's that, there would be nothing here that would require PLL or clock reference

It was just a marking example
